# Rails sum model def instead of column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Rails app that includes invoicing.

I use this def in the invoice controller:

```
def invoice_total
  self.invtimes.sum('price') + self.invexpenses.sum('price') + self.invaddhocs.sum('price') + self.invitems.sum('price') - self.payments.sum('amount')
end
```

Is there a way to sum `invoice_total` ?

I tried this:

```
<td><%= Invoice.notdraft.where("invoice_date >= ? AND invoice_date < ?", janday, febday).sum(:invoice_total) %></td>
```

But, Rails tells me:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "invoice_total" does not exist
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `.sum` is an ActiveRecord method to trigger a SQL `SUM`. But you use it with a method defined in your Model (not available in SQL). You'll have to sum it with Ruby code, not at the SQL level. --- I think there is a SQL way to retrieve `invoice_total` as a "fake" column (and then sum it via SQL). We would need help from pros of PostgreSQL to achieve this.

Comment: MrYoshiji - thanks!  I changed it to use .each and then added the values.  If you post as answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling an ActiveRecord method which triggers a SQL `SUM`, but the argument you pass to this method is a method defined in the Model (Ruby is aware of it, SQL is one level deeper and does not know it).

You have two options:

- Change the `.invoice_total` to a SQL sum in the select, meaning the logic you do in the `.invoice_total` method can be done via SQL, but I can't help you with that, I am not that good with PostgreSQL...
- Use ruby to calculate the sum of the `invoice_total`, something like `Invoice.your_scopes.map(&:invoice_total).inject(:+)`